# Oracle Forms 12C Changing the color of a data cell based on 30 days or later condition

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, report, background-color

I'm a longtime reader of Stack Overflow, but I rarely post questions. If I don't supply you with all of the information needed to help, please let me know and I will add it in.

I am using Oracle Forms (very much a newbie) and I am pulling data into a Tabular page. The table populates correctly. I have a drop down list with the values of 30, 60, and 90, indicating how far out I wish to check to see if a contract has expired. The canvas is TAB_CONTRACTS, the tab is TAB_CONTRACTS_TABLE. The data block where the drop down list is CBLK_TB (which might be an issue in and of itself). The name of the drop down list is DDL_EXPIRED. There are 5000 rows in my data set. I have a WHEN_LIST_CHANGED trigger with the following code (I'm trying to get 30 right before I add on 60 and 90).

```
DECLARE EXPIRE_CHECK VARCHAR2 (10000);
BEGIN
   EXPIRE_CHECK := get_block_property ('DB_CONTRACTS_TABLE', first_item);
   while (EXPIRE_CHECK is not null) loop
    if :DB_CONTRACTS_TABLE.CONTRACT_END_DATE > (sysdate + 30)
        then
      set_item_instance_property ('DB_CONTRACTS_TABLE.CONTRACT_END_DATE', BACKGROUND_COLOR, 'r255,g255,b000');
      end if;
      :DB_CONTRACTS_TABLE.CONTRACT_END_DATE := get_item_property ('DB_CONTRACTS_TABLE.CONTRACT_END_DATE', nextitem);
      
   end loop;
END;
```

The form compiles without an issue. When I select the dropdown box and select 30, I receive a "WHEN_LIST_CHANGE trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06502" message, which us usually thrown when a variable is being passed a value too large for it to handle. The only variable that I can see being affected is the loop variable (EXPIRE_CHECK), hence the large declaration of size (for testing, I'd rather go bigger than smaller and then optimize the code once it is functioning).

I have tried all sorts of code that I found online, carefully modified to fit into my code without issues. The code sample listed in my request is simply the latest test code I have found/come up with. I have examples of other code I have tried if anyone needs (or would like to see it).

What information do you need from me in order to assist me with this question? You will have to forgive me; it's early and I recently quit caffeine cold turkey, so there very well might be some obvious information I forgot to include.

Comment: What is DB_CONTRACTS_TABLE.CONTRACT_END_DATE field's **datatype**? You are comparing it to DATE. Apart from that, set **breakpoint** to the 3rd line (in code you posted) and then run form in **debug mode**. Forms will lead you through this trigger step-by-step and you'll exactly know which piece of code raised the error.

Comment: The datatype for CONTRACT_END_DATE is Date in the database and in the properties of the Oracle Forms object. Hmmm. I tried to run the form and it's coming up to a blank grey screen. I need to fix this before I move forward with debugging. Thanks for you advice.